# How to toggle visibility of several divs separately

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a series of text links that toggle visibility of a div element. The text links are styled to look like buttons and the text is being changed when the div is visible or invisible.

The problem is that when the first link is pressed, it toggles the visibility of it's own div plus all the other hidden divs and what is needed is that each link toggles the visibility of it's own div.

My question is what is the best way to solve this problem using only one function. Below is my code. Thanks!

The code can be also tested here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/eBfxB/

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide" id="plus">See all</a>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">

          <h2>Content One</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide" id="plus">See all</a>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">

          <h2>Content Two</h2>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#plus").text("Hide all")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#plus").text("See all")
       }
       );
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.show_hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: ids must be unique on the page, so the first step would be to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `toggle()` that accepts two callbacks have been deprecated and removed, so you'll have to use click instead and do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $(self).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "Hide all" ? "See all" : "Hide all";
               });
           });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/eBfxB/1/)

Note the use of the classes only (ID's must be unique) and the `this` keyword

Comment: just tested and it does what I need, however I am being pushed to the top of the page when I click any of the buttons, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It happens because they are anchors with a hash as the href, and that's what anchors with a hash as the href do, they link to "top". Add preventDefault() to the handler to make it stop, I'll edit the answer.